# Actual purpose of Neo

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix

I recently watched Matrix trilogy, *yet again* (probably 25th time!). This time I made some new conclusions, and I am confused regarding this one. In first part, i.e., *The Matrix*. Morpheus tells Neo that there was a guy before him who could bend rules inside the Matrix and was the "One" to free the first of the humans, and that a prophecy was made by the *Oracle* that he will return, which is concluded at the end that Neo is in fact the *One*.

If we forget *Reloaded* and *Revolutions* at this point, it seems that Neo's purpose is to free humans from the Matrix, which we can see when he calls machine from phone booth and tells it that he is coming.

Now if we focus on *Reloaded*, it seems as if his *purpose* is altered. Architect tells him that he should return to the source and *re-build* Zion, which he refuses to obey.

Getting on to *Revolutions*, Neo finally ends up helping machines get control over the Matrix in exchange for peace.

So after watching all the three movies and the considering the prophecy my question is what was the *real* purpose of Neo, after all?

Comment: If you consider that Morpheus is the only *human* in these "prophecies"; then you will realise that Neo's true purpose is to serve the machines: The Oracle, The Architect and Deus Ex Machina. Morpheus is told nothing more than what he needs to be told in order to find Neo **that is his only purpose**; from that point onwards, it's up to Neo to figure out that he is in fact The One, and fulfil his destiny of re-stabilising the Matrix. "Freeing" humans is not actually his purpose.

Comment: See also: [What flaw in the Matrix was Neo supposed to correct?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93516/21267) and [Why Did the Machines Even Bother With a Matrix?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12223/21267)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neo's machine made purpose is as a controlled failure check valve for "errors" that add up in the Matrix. Of course these errors are humans who reject the matrix. The machines use the Neo to control how the system works and minimize the number of malfunctioning battery crops (pod humans). Of course, this results in the unpredictable because Neo is mostly human and doesn't follow orders.

The human goal for "the one" is absolute freedom of all humans. This is more faith than "real defined purpose" as humans had no hand in Neo's creation. Previous ones did not have the will power, actual power, or power of friendship in order to free all humans, so they did the best they could to ensure even a false hope of freedom lived through a new cycle of rebellion.

Answer (score 0):

Neo's goal has never been altered, the thing is you are misleading persons in the matrix which are computer programs with real humans. People who must be saved from the matrix are only those who are connected to it, so rescuing Zion from the bots will help the human to get rid of robots revolution, and not beeing keeped in the human farms robots are using.

So eventually by saving Zion, and restarting a Agent free Matrix will make Neo able to keep humans from Zion safe, and restart a virus free computer programm (the matrix) in which no humans are trapped (only programs).

The thing is we don't know if it is possible to free all of the cocooned humans from where Neo rebirthed. Clear enough ? Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok long explanation but it will be worth the while, Neo is just an anomaly that arises because of an imbalance of the matrix equation. So are Morpheus, Trinity, and everybody else. So to put them back into the matrix and have control over them, the architect had created a second layer of the matrix for the ppl who reject the matrix, but ultimately it's for control over them. Yes, I know they unjack their heads and everything, but they are still in the matrix, just not the basic human version.

To answer your other question about Neo's purpose:
The One is a made-up concept and the whole thing is a fake world created and the Oracle knew this and she also knew the big picture that is for the humans and machines to coexist hence she played along in each version if the matrix.